# Create bootstrap form having horizontal and vertical form field

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Is there anyway I can create a form using bootstrap which can have fields aligned in same line as well as horizontal fields?

[image]

Something like this?

in this the cvv MM and YY are in the same line..How can i make it possible using bootstrap form?

```
<form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label><input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" />
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">CVV</label><input type="email" class="form-control" id="cvv" />
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" />
                </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I want the cvv to be aligned with the first form field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your input fields in a div and assign a `col-sm-x` class to it e.g:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="cardNumber">Card # (required)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cardNumber" size="12" autocomplete='off'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also add a col-sm-x to your labels

For columns:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Expiry date(MM/YYYY) (required)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM" size="2" autocomplete='off'>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY" size="4" autocomplete='off'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, class of form should be `form-horizontal` Play with the col width as you like

Comment: This is actually not the question I asked.I want to know if I could have two fields in a single row?

Comment: Yes thats the answer.Use columns.

Comment: Can you update your answer with two input field?So that I can mark it accepted if its working?

Comment: I was under the impression that a `form-group` class should only contain one label and one input, but maybe I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your input fields as above in one div but add to this div the 'form-inline' class. No need of the col-sm-x class.

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <label class="control-label">Expiry date(MM/YYYY) (required)</label>   
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM" size="2" autocomplete='off'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY" size="4" autocomplete='off'>
    </div>
</div>
```