# Two fields on the same line in a vertical form with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I would like the fields "Name" and "Last Name" to be on the same row.

I've found some solutions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867313/create-bootstrap-form-having-horizontal-and-vertical-form-field) here in stackoverflow, but the problem is that I want the labels positioned above the fields to be side by side too.

How is that possible?

[image]

Here's the form code:

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name here" value="Leandro">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputLastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Enter your last name here" value="Faria">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputTitle">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Enter your title here" value="CEO">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email here" value="leo@saasmetrics.co">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group bottom-buffer">
    <label for="selectEmail">Notifications:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectEmailNotifications">
      <option>None</option>
      <option>Daily</option>
      <option>Weekly</option>
      <option selected>Monthly</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group bottom-buffer">
    <label for="selectEmail">Status:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectEmailNotifications">
      <option selected>Active</option>
      <option>Inactive</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group bottom-buffer">
    <label for="selectEmail">Profile:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectEmailNotifications">
      <option selected>Administrator</option>
      <option>User</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should get you started.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name here" value="Leandro">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputLastName">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Enter your last name here" value="Faria">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the class 'row' not is need for me...!

Comment: @FábioZangirolami it may appear as if you don't need it, but you do. If you omit the row, the left and right margin will be messed up and your floating col-sm-6's will no longer be contained in a block level row.

Comment: I treated it with `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) ... padding-left ... padding-right ... `
tks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the top answer is true, but this is another solution.You can use inline bootstrap forms like this:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 50%">
        <label for="input1">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="David">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="width: 49%">
        <label for="input2">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Tanner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Read the [bootstrap document](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)